# What api documentation tool can be used for Spring boot-Azure function?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-2, azure-functions, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Azure functions use HTTP trigger(HTTP protocol) not exactly the REST. Enough resource is available for API documentation for Spring-Rest but not for Spring-Azure

Answer (score 1):

The [official way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition) to generate OpenAPI definitions with Azure Functions is to use Azure API Management (APIM) to generate it for you. There is even a [consumption tier for APIM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-api-management-consumption-tier-is-now-generally-available/) which pairs well as a custom gateway for Azure Functions.

The same should work with Spring Cloud Functions deployed on Azure too.